# Autoboxing 0 to Generic Number

Tags: java, generics, numbers, autoboxing

Maybe I just have a knot in my synapses...

```
  public static <T extends Number> T firstNonZero(T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
      if (value.doubleValue() != 0.0) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return (T) 0;      // Cannot cast from int to T
  }
```

I guess I don't need to explain the above method. My problem is that I need to "generate" a zero of type `T`.

How do I do that?

Comment: return Integer.class.cast(0)

Comment: Shouldn't a method called `firstNonZero` really return `null` instead if no non-zero value can be found, instead of zero, or even raise an exception?

Comment: It must not return `null`, that would be pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, how about :

```
  public static <T extends Number> T firstNonZero(T... values) {
    T zero = null;
    for (T value : values) {
      if (value.doubleValue() != 0.0) {
        return value;
      } else {
        zero = value;
      }
    }
    return zero;
  }
```

This is assuming at least one value is passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static <T extends Number> T firstNonZero(T... values) {
        for (T value : values) {
          if (value.doubleValue() != 0.0) {
            return value;
          }
        }
        return (T)Integer.class.cast(0);      // Double class can do too but give 0.0 if double or we will have ClassCastException
      }
```

Also 0 number parameter will work in this case

Comment: I don't think this will work. Try it with `double d = firstNonZero(0.0);` And if you change it to `Double.class.cast`, try with `int d = firstNonZero(0);`

Comment: @tobias_k no it does not fail for double d = firstNonZero(0.0); as I just tried and  regarding your second query about Double.class.cast I updated the answer comments ' Double class can do too but give 0.0 if double'

Comment: fails: `assertEquals(new Long(0), NumberUtilities.firstNonZero(0L));`